# Generate different hmac for the same request

Tags: php, security, cryptography, hmac

I'm using Phalcon PHP and I'd like to secure my API with hmac method so I'll take the request payload and create the hash with a special order (the client know this order):

```
$secret = 'my-secret'
$body = $this->request->getJsonRawBody(); // Get raw body data

// Build hmac payload with request parameters
$payload = $body->param2 . $body->param3 . $body->param1
// Generate hmac
$local_hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret);
```

So I have the idea to use a timestamp or random string. For example the client set a custom header in the request (`Header-Time: 1561106848`) then I can use it inside the payload. But it doesn't change anything because if somebody intercept the request he can just executes it and the hmac will work.

There is something to generate a different hmac every time  ?

Comment: HMAC generates the same output for the same input and key by design (how else would you verify the signature?) However, adding a timestamp to the input for replay protection is very typical. Just verify that the timestamp is within some reasonable distance from $now.

Comment: @Peter Yeah you're right I think I'll create a timestamp and watch if I have more than 60seconds of difference between now and the timestamp sent

Comment: @Peter there is something when the client change his hour to get a independent timestamp ?

Comment: I don't understand. How often the signature changes depends only on the resolution of the timestamp. If you use second resolution (i.e. "normal" unix timestamps), the signature changes very second. If you are asking about clock drift then yes, this is a downside of this approach. Both sides have to have somewhat accurate clocks, otherwise messages get erroneously rejected. That's not usually a problem in practice, though, thanks to NTP. Lots of things assume accurate clocks.

Comment: @Peter Yes I'm talking about clock. If the client change his clock on his mobile, the application hasn't the same timestamp as the server